# Laravel count has many through without n+1

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 4 models that are relevant.

`Company`

`Location`

`Customer`

`ThirdPartyLinkClick`

Company.php

```
public function locations() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Location');
    }
```

Location.php

```
public function customers() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Customer');
}

public function linkClicks() {
   return $this->hasManyThrough('App\ThirdPartyLinkClick', 'App\Customer');
}
```

Customer.php

```
public function linkClicks() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\ThirdPartyLinkClick');
}
```

There is no issue when acquiring the count of link clicks for all customers when on a single `Location`.

I can simply do: `$this->linkClicks->count();` which creates a query where it does a `WHERE IN (1,2,3,4, etc)` query

However, on a Company page, I want to also get this count, but avoid an `n+1`

Right now, my model method on Company.php is

```
public function getTotalClicksToReviewSites() {
  $locations = $this->locations;

  $clicks = 0;
  foreach ($locations as $location) {
    $clicks += $location->linkClicks->count();
  }

  return $clicks;
      
}
```

This creates duplicate queries where it checks location_id on each query. There will be a query for every location rather than checking a group of id's in a `WHERE IN` statement.

How can I do an eloquent query that will use a single query to gather this data? I only need the count.

Comment: link clicks is essentially 4 models away from company (i.e. company > location > customer > linkClick) I don't think eloquent supports this you would need to do the joins manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use eager loading.

```
$companies = Company::with('locations', 'locations.linkClicks')->get();
```

This prevents n + 1 query problem, so, to get te total of linkClicks for each company youur function will work or simply you can do.

```
$companies = Company::with('locations', 'locations.linkClicks')
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($company) {
        $company->linkClicksCount = $company->locations->sum(function ($location) {
            return $location->linkClicks->count();
        });
        
        return $company;
    });
```

The output should be something like this (a new property linkClicksCount added on each company).

```
[
    {"id": 1, "name": "Company 1", "linkClicksCount": 9, "locations": [], ...},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Company 2", "linkClicksCount": 3, "locations": [], ...},
    ...
]
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked exactly as I needed. n+1 queries (35) down to a single query.